# Maven build fails at site default-deploy

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-release-plugin, maven-site-plugin

I have been struggling to fix my maven build issue from last 2 days with no success almost. Can you please help me on this?

1. I have a parent pom.xml which looks like

   ```
   <distributionmanagement>
       Repository...
       Snapshot 
       <site>
           site config here..
       </site>
   </distributionmanagement>
   ```
2. In child pom.xml, which I wrote works fine if I do 'mvn install'. tar file is created and appears in project/target folder. Looks good so far...
3. When I do release the problem comes. The good thing is, it goes well till end - creates tar, uploads tar into my svn repository.. but after that maven is trying to read parent pom.xml and error comes while running "maven-site-plugin:default-deploy" and then "BUILD FAILURE"

What I'm thinking is - since tar is created and uploaded into subversion repository creating site & deploying is not required for us. How can I say to maven that once tar is created don't do anything and that's the end point for me. In other words - don't run anything 'site' related stuff for me?

=========================
UPDATE

I have my release plugin config as below

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <tagBase></tagBase>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

we actually do release from our batch file which consists of mvn statements like below -

> ```
> call mvn clean
> call mvn install
> call mvn -B release:prepare -DdryRun=true -DscmCommentPrefix="somecomment"
> call mvn -B release:clean 
> call mvn -B release:prepare -DscmCommentPrefix="somecomment"
> call mvn -B release:perform -DscmCommentPrefix="somecomment"
> ```

Can you please suggest me now?

Comment: Why not using a repository manager like Artifactory, Nexus or achiva instead of SVN repository?

Answer (score 1):

You should change the [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html) configuration no to do an site-deploy which is default like the following:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <goals>deploy</goals>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if creating site & deploying is really not required (as you say in your question), you could just remove the `<distributionManagement>` section. According to the docs default goals are "either deploy or deploy site-deploy, if the project has a `<distributionManagement>`/`<site>` element".

http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html